# How to assign the result of splitting a string to a variable in Twilio Studio Flow?

Tags: twilio-studio

I need to split the input of the conversation on different variables:

I send the message `Name|Lastname|+549111122222`, when I receive the incoming Conversation in Studio Flow, I need to split the data in three variables (`name`, `lastname` and `phone`)

First, I created a `Set Variables` widget with the key `input` and the value `{{trigger.conversation.Body | split: '|'}}`.

[image]

When I execute the flow, the result is not an array but a string without the '|' characters:

```
"input": {
  "input": "DiegoROMERO+561111444444"
}
```

I would expect this:

```
"input": {
  "input": ["Diego","ROMERO","+561111444444"]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because all variable are of datatype string, i.e. the array will be casted to a string when it's saved as a variable.

From what I can tell, you have two options.

1. Store name, lastname, and phone in three different variables.
2. Move the entire logic from a "studio variable" into a [liquid variable](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide/liquid-template-language).